# python twill module submit a form

Tags: python, python-2.7, ubuntu, python-module, twill

Hello I am currently trying to make a bot that registers itself on a website.
My Code is following:

```
from twill.commands import fv, code, follow, go, submit, browser
from time import sleep
import random

emailProviders = ["@yahoo.com", "@web.de", "@gmail.com"]

def userChoice():
        invLink = raw_input("[ZenGamingBot] Enter your invitation Link-> ")
        userName = raw_input("[ZenGamingBot] Enter a Username for the Bot-> ")
        count = 0
        while True:
                count += 1
                regBot(invLink, userName, count)

def regBot(invLink, userName, count):
        invLink = invLink.strip("http://")
        invLink = "http://" + invLink
        username = userName + str(count)
        email = userName + str(count) + random.choice(emailProviders)
        password = userName + str(count) + "345"

        go(invLink)
        code("200")
        print "[ZenGamingBot] Loaded Website successfully!"
        sleep(1)
        follow("ENTER NOW")
        url=browser.get_url()
        print url
        fv("2", "fos_user_registration_form_username", username)
        fv("2", "fos_user_registration_form_email", email)
        fv("2", "fos_user_registration_form_plainPassword_first", password)
        submit('Enter')

        print "[ZenGamingBot] Successfully registerd Bot #" + str(count) + "\n "
        print "Username: " + username + "\n"
        print "Email: " + email + "\n"
        print "Password: " + password + "\n"

def main():
        userChoice()
main()
```

This Bot is made to register at http://zengaming.co/register/ it go to the link of an invitation code and registers. I get following output:

```
[ZenGamingBot] Enter your invitation Link-> http://zengaming.co/r?zen=1179068
[ZenGamingBot] Enter a Username for the Bot-> BotTestName
==> at http://zengaming.co/welcome
[ZenGamingBot] Loaded Website successfully!
==> at http://zengaming.co/register/
Note: submit is using submit button: name="None", value="Enter"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ZenGamingBot.py", line 39, in <module>
    main()
  File "ZenGamingBot.py", line 38, in main
    userChoice()
  File "ZenGamingBot.py", line 13, in userChoice
    regBot(invLink, userName, count)
  File "ZenGamingBot.py", line 30, in regBot
    submit('Enter')
  File "/home/invasi0nz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twill/commands.py", line 359, in submit
    browser.submit(submit_button)
  File "/home/invasi0nz/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twill/browser.py", line 393, in submit
    headers=headers
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 508, in post
    return self.request('POST', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 451, in request
    prep = self.prepare_request(req)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 382, in prepare_request
    hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 304, in prepare
    self.prepare_url(url, params)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 362, in prepare_url
    to_native_string(url, 'utf8')))
requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL '/register/': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http:///register/?
```